# How to change shell in script temporary in sunOS?

Tags: bash, scripting, sunos

The machine has default shell "sh" and running SunOS. I try to run the script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9
echo $NLS_LANG
```

I get the output:

NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9^M: is not an identifier

I think the script cannot execute this command but do not understand why. Maybe It is because the default shell is not bash shell.

Could you help me to convert sh shell into bash shell inside of the script.

P.S: I have also tried with #!/bin/sh but result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that Bash is where you say it is? Consider using the following shebang:

```
bash-3.2$ cat ./test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9
echo $NLS_LANG
```

Ensure your shell script is executable:

```
bash-3.2$ chmod +x ./test.sh
bash-3.2$ ls -l ./test.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 paj  staff  81 26 Apr 11:52 ./test.sh
```

And run...

```
bash-3.2$ ./test.sh
AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9
```

Comment: Thank you Johnsyweb I have found my mistake. I have tried to run with #sh test.sh  so that it wont work. I tried with #./test.sh and it works. Thanks to everybody...

Comment: Happy to help. You shouldn't need to type anything before `./test.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is using the wrong line endings. Run it through `dos2unix`.

Comment: Now I get the output: NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9: is not an identifier

Comment: How are you executing the script?